# How to subtract a substring from a string in web harvest

Tags: java, javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, webharvest

I am new to webharvest and am using it to get the article data from a website, using the following statement:

```
let $text := data($doc//div[@id="articleBody"])
```

and this is the data that I get from the above statement :

```
The Refine Spa (Furman's Mill) was built as a stone grist mill along the on a tributary of Capoolong Creek by Moore Furman, quartermaster general of George Washington's army

Notable people

Notable current and former residents of Pittstown include:
```

My question is that, is it possible to subtract a string from another 
in the above example : "Notable people" from the content.

Is it possible to do this way? If its possible please let me know how. Thanks.
Is there something that I can do like this:

```
if (*contains*($text, 'Notable people')) then $text := *minus*($text, 'Notable people')
```

*contains* is a example function name to determine is a string is a substring of another,
 and *minus* is a example function name to remove a substring from another

The desired output:

```
The Refine Spa (Furman's Mill) was built as a stone grist mill along the on a tributary of Capoolong Creek by Moore Furman, quartermaster general of George Washington's army

Notable current and former residents of Pittstown include:
```

Comment: Sure it is possible, you can do it by manually searching and making substring or with regex/literal replacement

Comment: There is a java function that does the *String minus* I found this : http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#function on how to define your own function. If there a way to call a java function from web harvest?

Answer (score 1):

From http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php :

> regexp
>
> Searches the body for the given regular expression and optionally replaces found occurrences with specified pattern.
> If body is a list of values then the regexp processor is applied to every item and final execution result is the list.

You just have to use correct regular expression a correct `regexp-pattern` and correct `regexp-result`

Comment: I dont have regex, the content to be replaced keeps changing. Instead I have the content to be replaced.

Comment: Changing how? Literal to be replaced is almost a regex, just needs some special character escaping.

Comment: There is no specific pattern of the data so that it can be represented with a regex. As an alternative if we consider to use the data it self as regex, escaping meta characters becomes much more complicated task. Please let me know what u think.

Comment: I was writing about changing webharvest source code when i tried to search for conversion to regex. If done in java it is pretty easy since you can use `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String)`. Changing webharvest source code seems easy too, so you can add literal replacement operation yourself based on regular expression operation code. Also you could ask author to add such simple operation but webpage seems quite old